# ImportError: cannot import name 'forms' from 'basicapp'

Tags: python, django, importerror

form.py:

```
from django import forms

class FormName(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField()
    email=forms.EmailField()
    text=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import forms

def index(request):
    return render(request,'basicapp/index.html')

def form_page(request):
    Form = forms.FormName()
    return render(request,'basicapp/form_page.html',{'form':Form})
```

I dont know what is wrong here! when I run server, it makes an error, saying `ImportError : cannot import name 'forms' from 'basicapp'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you have named your forms file, form.py and you are trying to access a module called forms. Rename `form.py` file to `forms.py`.

Second, you are trying to import `forms` from your forms file. This is actually referencing `forms` you imported via `from django import forms`. You have a couple options here. In your view file you can either `import .forms` or `from .forms import FormName` I prefer the latter.

So, after you rename `form.py` to `forms.py` I would rewrite `views.py` to look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import FormName

def index(request):
    return render(request,'basicapp/index.html')

def form_page(request):
    this_form = FormName()
    return render(request,'basicapp/form_page.html',{'form':this_form})
```

Comment: Thanks for your effective answer

Comment: but i want to know what's the problem in my previous code?

Comment: 1. Forms file had the wrong name. Should be forms.py based on `from .forms` in your view. 2. You are importing forms from .forms in your view which is the django forms module and not the your forms. Compare my answer with your code to see the differences. Hope this clears things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You made **two** mistakes in your code

**1**)  Your form file should be named **forms.py** and not **form.pY**
**2**)  your views.py import code should be

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from basicapp import forms
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue in your view.py

replace
below line

```
from .forms import forms
```

with

```
from <your app name>.forms import forms
```

You are getting this error because django is trying to find it in root folder where your manage.py exist.